# Create a sript for "point sampling tool" of QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

Is there any way to create a python script to the "point sampling tool" plugin from QGIS?

I have a very large number of Netcdf files which I want extrat the values from pixels to a irregular points shapefile.

Any idea?

Comment: I have  a very large number of netcdf files of precipitation forecast by 2001 to 2014 years, including june, july, August and September months in each year. I want to extract the netcdf values to a point layer of my weather stations using point sampling tool plugin in a python script. How can I do this? Can anyone help me? Thank's